# User permission / type logic in C# MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, partial-views

I'm working on a small project that is using MVC 5. I have a Projects/Details page which displays information of a given project. Each project have multiple members and there can be 3 member types. These types have different information and functions available on the page. My current temporary solution is basic, in my View I have an if statement to check the type of the logged in user and show a partial view accordingly. To me this solution feels kind of "hacky", I'm sure there's a better way. So my question is: how would you go about implementing such functionality?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three ways in which you may want to approach this.

1) Even if you think your proposed solution is "hacky", it is actually not a bad idea. I personally did it in a project. I created partial views depending on the roles a user had; however, you'd be adding extra business logic to the view. Try experimenting with it, and see how it performs when deployed. This should be your first try since it's actually your idea, and by experimenting you'll learn considerably.

2) Have you tried checking in the controller for a user's roles, and depending on that role returning a specific view? In this case, the business logic will remain in the controller, and it is considered a good practice.

3) Even if I don't know whether you are using an ORM (Entity Framework) or connecting directly to a SQL database, try retrieving a member's roles using a stored procedure and checking for its roles in a DB handler class.

As you may see, there are three options to check for a member's roles.

Finally, I recommend you reading about claims/roles-based authorization. It may help you in future projects:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/Asp-Net-mvc5-role-base-accessibility/

Comment: I'm using claims already, that is how I currently check the UserType in my View. I completely forgot about option 2, I was so fixed on the default routing (Action name and View name being the same and returning View(model) ) I didn't even think about returning specific View for a specific role. Thanks for your answer, I'll go with option 2.